# Can not import reactjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I'm trying to import react, I wrote the following code:

```
import React from "react";
```

but when I write `npm start` in the terminal it shows me these errors:

```
> reactjs-basics@1.0.0 start /home/zx-coder/Downloads/reactjs-basics-master
> npm run build


> reactjs-basics@1.0.0 build /home/zx-coder/Downloads/reactjs-basics-master
> webpack -d && cp src/index.html dist/index.html && webpack-dev-server --content-base src/ --inline --hot

 Hash: 2692c371e3a85309b95e Version: webpack 1.15.0 Time: 1020ms
        Asset    Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
    bundle.js  166 kB       0  [emitted]  main bundle.js.map  184 kB       0  [emitted]  main
    + 37 hidden modules events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

 Error: listen EADDRINUSE 127.0.0.1:8080
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1044:20)
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1367:14)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1408:12)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.doListen [as callback] (net.js:1517:7)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:97:10)

 npm ERR! Linux 4.15.0-29-generic npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node"
 "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "build" npm ERR! node v8.10.0 npm ERR! npm 
 v3.5.2 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! reactjs-basics@1.0.0 build:
 `webpack -d &&cp src/index.html dist/index.html && webpack-dev-server
--content-base src/ --inline --hot` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the reactjs-basics@1.0.0 build script 'webpack -d
 && cp src/index.html dist/index.html && webpack-dev-server
--content-base src/ --inline --hot'. npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed. npm ERR! If you do, this
 is most likely a problem with the reactjs-basics package, npm ERR! not
 with npm itself. npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your
 system: npm ERR!     webpack -d && cp src/index.html dist/index.html
 && webpack-dev-server --content-base src/ --inline --hot npm ERR! You
 can get information on how to open an issue for this project with: npm
 ERR!     npm bugs reactjs-basics npm ERR! Or if that isn't available,
 you can get their info via: npm ERR!     npm owner ls reactjs-basics
 npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

 npm ERR! Please include the following file with anysupport request:
 npm ERR!    
 /home/zx-coder/Downloads/reactjs-basics-master/npm-debug.log

 npm ERR! Linux 4.15.0-29-generic npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node"
 "/usr/bin/npm" "start" npm ERR! node v8.10.0 npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2 npm
 ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! reactjs-basics@1.0.0 start: `npm run
 build` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the
 reactjs-basics@1.0.0 start script 'npm run build'. npm ERR! Make sure
 you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed. npm ERR! If
 you do, this is most likely a problem with the reactjs-basics package,
 npm ERR! not with npm itself. npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails
 on your system: npm ERR!     npm run build npm ERR! You can get
 information on how to open an issue for this project with: npm ERR!   
 npm bugs reactjs-basics npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can
 get their info via: npm ERR!     npm owner ls reactjs-basics npm ERR!
 There is likely additional logging output above.

 npm ERR! Please include the following file with anysupport request:
 npm ERR!    
 /home/zx-coder/Downloads/reactjs-basics-master/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: can you give us info about what os you have?

Comment: I'm using kubuntu

Comment: What does that have to do with importing React? Did you read the error message? It's telling you that port 8080 is already in use.

Comment: if you want to learn basics of rect and play around with components, try create-react-app.. You dont have to worry about any of the complex config, until you eject..

Comment: How to change the port ?

Comment: Ask a new question about changing the port.  You didn't read the error message you were provided before asking this question.  It doesn't show research effort.

Answer (score 0):

The error is `Error: listen EADDRINUSE 127.0.0.1:8080` which means there already is something that uses port 8080 on your machine, try changing the port webpack starts the dev server

Comment: How to change the port?

Comment: What package did you use to create the react project?

Comment: @AymanTarig are you sure you have node and npm properly installed? you should have got creat-react-app working out of the box if everything else is fine

Comment: @SoorajSethumadhavan yes I've both of them istalled

Comment: if my answer helped you consider marking it as correct so people that have the same problem will know how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

solution 1: if your are beginner - just restart your PC.

solution 2: open task manager and kill all node instances.

alternatively you check if there is some other react app already running on port 8080 so you have to stop it

OR

you have to change your current app port to some other port.